# Brownian motion and its maximum and its minimum

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, st.statistics, brownian-motion

Let $W_u, 0\leq u \leq t$ be Brownian motion.
Let $m_t= min_{0\leq u\leq t} W_u$ and $M_t = max_{0 \leq u \leq t} W_u$.

The fact that $(M_t , W_t)$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is known in some stochastic calculus book.

By symmetry of Brownian motion, $(m_t,W_t)$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I want to know whether $(m_t, M_t , W_t)$ is absolutely continuous with respect  to Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Since
$P(x\leq m_t \leq M_t \leq y, W_t \in dx) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \bigg{[} \phi \big( \frac{x-2k(b-a)}{\sqrt{t}}) - \phi \big( \frac{x-2b-2k(b-a)}{\sqrt{t}}) \bigg{]}dx$,

If $(m_t,M_t,W_t)$ is absolutely continuous to Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^3$, I think I can calculate joint density of $m_t,M_t,W_t$.

Could you help me?

Comment: If it's true, it ought to be possible to prove by similar techniques to $(M_t, W_t)$.  Have you tried to work through it?  For instance, I would guess that the Malliavin calculus approach would work. On the other hand, if you can calculate formally what the density "should" be, then you can probably turn that into a proof that it really is.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that a proof is given in

*Choi, ByoungSeon; Roh, JeongHo*, [**On the trivariate joint distribution of Brownian motion and its maximum and minimum**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.spl.2012.12.015), Stat. Probab. Lett. 83, No. 4, 1046-1053 (2013). [ZBL1266.60142](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1266.60142).

Comment: What is the part that contains the proof?

Comment: I don't have access to the paper itself, but the abstract seems to suggest that it has a proof. Is that not the case?

Comment: The paper in question does not anywhere use or claim there exists a joint density of $(m_t, M_t, W_t)$. In the cited paper, what the authors' call the 'trivariate joint density' refers to the density
$P(a\leq m_t \leq M_t \leq b, W_t \in dx)$ for _fixed_ $a \leq 0 \leq  b$.